# Concatenating a column to a file

Tags: shell, command, paste

I tried to concatenate a column to a text file.
The column looks like this:

```
14_00

132_1



343_12

23


2
2_1
```

It is made of numbers and spaces (when no number is specified)

The other file I want to add this column to (at the beginning of the file) is made of numbers separated by tabs ans has the same number of rows as the first file.

I tried the following command:

```
paste -d "\t" file1.txt file2.txt > merged.txt
```

It works fine except that, for some reason, I have a "^M" at the end of the first column.

Where does this ^M come from and how can I get rid of it?
I tried changing the delimiters in the paste options, but the problem remains.

Comment: Your first file has CRLF (Windows/DOS) line endings.  Unix doesn't mind whether there's a CR before the NL (LF) that marks the end of line, so it kept the CR as part of the line from the first file, and added the line from the second file.  Convert the files to Unix first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I have a "^M" at the end of the first`

That means you have `\r` in the files itself.

To get rid of them you can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak $'s/\r$//' file
```

OR use: `dos2unix` utility.